# Mock function for express functions

Tags: javascript, express, testing, mocking, jestjs

I have a server.js file it has an app.get function. I want to test this function using "jest". I am getting difficulty to write a mock function of the app.get function below.

```
app.get('/api/getUser', (req, res) => {
    res.json({
        'email': req.email,
        'name': req.username
    });
});
```

Comment: You might want to look at something like [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest).

Answer (score 2):

Here is the unit test solution, besides, you can write the integration test using [supertest](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest)

`server.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/api/getUser', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    email: req.email,
    name: req.username,
  });
});
```

`server.test.js`:

```js
const express = require('express');

jest.mock('express', () => {
  const express = {
    get: jest.fn(),
  };
  return jest.fn(() => express);
});

describe('60562419', () => {
  it('should send json', () => {
    const mApp = express();
    const mReq = { email: 'example@gmail.com', username: 'jest' };
    const mRes = { json: jest.fn() };
    mApp.get.mockImplementationOnce((route, handler) => {
      handler(mReq, mRes);
    });
    require('./server');
    expect(express).toBeCalled();
    expect(mApp.get).toBeCalledWith('/api/getUser', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mRes.json).toBeCalledWith({ email: 'example@gmail.com', name: 'jest' });
  });
});
```

Unit test results with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60562419/server.test.js (9.939s)
  60562419
    ✓ should send json (581ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 server.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.476s
```

Comment: i used app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist'))); in my  server.js, on runing node server.js, it works fine, but on running npm test, it show an error express.static is not a function. why?

Comment: @rahulsharma I guess you didn't mock `express.static` method.

Comment: I am beginner in testing, may u please tell me how can i mock express.static